# Multiple Inner joins in Linq with ToList() for datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

how to properly inner join a query? then after i wanna place it to a datagrid

my query statement:

```
var query = (from ent in ctx.entries
             join p in ctx.products on ent.prodId equals p.prodId
             join h in ctx.hospitals on ent.hospId equals h.hospId
             join c in ctx.contactPersons on ent.contId equals c.contId
             where ent.empId == Globals.empId
             select ent).ToList();
```

the error is `embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your query syntax. Is this by any change inside an If statement? Something like: if (condition) var query ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like:

```
var query = (from ent in ctx.entries
             where ent.empId = Globals.empId
             && ctx.Products.Any(a => a.prodId == ent.prodId)
             && ctx.hospitals.Any(a => a.hospId == ent.hospId)
             && ctx.contactPersons.Any(a => a.contId == ent.contId)
             select ent).ToList();
```

edit:
Based on the inner joins mentioned in the question.